# How to find the coefficient of adjustment of a company's daily quotation data in 2 years

Tags: r, statistics, finance

I need to find the adjustment coefficient to then find out the beta of the data regression and compare it with the performance of the Brazilian stock exchange (IBOV) in the same period.

I don't have the slightest idea how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Ariel Schreiber Dines! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Notably, it is often expected that you have done some [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3358272) before coming to SO in order to attempt code, instead of expecting this site to be a free-code service.